# Machine-learning input data distribution

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, dataset

I'm trying to build a binary 1/0 ML classification algorithm, and was thinking about how to set up the input dataset. If the event I want to predict (the 1's) occur relatively less frequently in the total data than the 0's, does it makes sense to pare the dataset in such a way to get a more equal distribution of 1's and 0's? Would that be falsely representing the data to the algorithm? What are the disadvantages to doing so?

Comment: You _can_ do that, but it would be better if you didn't have to throw away data. I imagine the reason this question came up is that you're optimizing your solution for _accuracy_, but the classes are skewed enough that a high-accuracy algorithm has really poor [_recall_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall). I would recommend optimizing for something other than accuracy (like minimizing a weighted sum of false negatives and false positives, more heavily weighting the false negatives).

Answer (score 1):

Define an accuracy metric that reasonably models how you want your algorithm to perform.

Once you have a metric in hand you can cross-validate this question and see if it is an improves the performance.

Some common accuracy metrics that model the problem different: Normalized mutual information, Gini on the labels argsorted by the probabilities, Precision, Recall, AUC.

If the classes are extremely unbalanced and FN are crucial, you'll see an improvement.